# How to install a cordova plugin from a GitHub pull request?

Tags: ios, cordova, github, wkwebview

iOS does not display a decimal point on the numeric keyboard in cordova apps. The workaround is to install the [cordova-plugin-decimal-keyboard](https://github.com/mrchandoo/cordova-plugin-decimal-keyboard) plugin. Trouble is, this plugin does not work with the improved UI engine **WKWebView**.

[EricD](https://github.com/ericdesa) kindly contributed a [fix](https://github.com/mrchandoo/cordova-plugin-decimal-keyboard/pull/12) but the pull request has not yet been merged. So, is it possible to install the plugin from the pull request and if so, what is the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way, as the creator of the PR did his work on his fork master branch is to install the plugin from the fork using the github url

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/ericdesa/cordova-plugin-decimal-keyboard`

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried that, but keep getting the error **Error: Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/ericdesa/cordova-plugin-decimal-keyboard.git via registry**

Comment: I'm going to fork and fix it as don't want to run the risk of EricD updating master that could result in me pulling in changes

Comment: Ah, right, the plugin doesn't have a package.json and it's now required. You can then fork the plugin and add it yourself or downgrade the cordova CLI version to 7.1.0 and use `--nofetch` in the plugin add command

Answer (score 1):

Although [@jcesarmobile's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1351469/jcesarmobile) answer is correct, that particular plugin could not be installed this way because it was missing a `package.json`

I therefore forked the project, tweaked the docs and published the renamed package to npm [cordova-plugin-decimal-keyboard-wkwebview](https://github.com/john-doherty/cordova-plugin-decimal-keyboard-wkwebview)